# How to modify route to use different path to another folder/controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controllers, maproute

My current app structure is as follows:

```
Controller
    UserAdminController
    GroupsAdminController
```

I want to modify it the way that for each administration group I have its own folder. For example:

```
Controller
     UserAdmin
         -UserAdminController
     GroupAdmin 
         -GroupAdminController
```

And in my view I want to point to particular controller's action:

```
@Html.ActionLink("User Administration", "Index","/UserAdmin/UserAdmin")
@Html.ActionLink("Group Administration", "Index", "/GroupAdmin/GroupAdmin")
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways, but I suggest reading up and using [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
Areas
     UserAdmin
         Controller
             -UserAdminController
     GroupAdmin
         Controller 
             -GroupAdminController
```

Also, ActionLink has many overloads one you can use needs ("text", "action", "controller", route values) as following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("User Administration", "Index","UserAdmin", new { area="UserAdmin" })
@Html.ActionLink("Group Administration", "Index", "GroupAdmin", new { area="GroupAdmin" })
```

Another option would be to have one area for Admin and just two controllers. Keep in mind that each controller gets its own folder for the views:

```
Areas
     Admin
         Controllers
             UserController
             GroupController
         Views
             User
                 Index.cshtml
             Group
                 Index.cshtml
```

Then your ActionLinks would be:

```
@Html.ActionLink("User Administration", "Index","User", new { area="Admin" })
@Html.ActionLink("Group Administration", "Index", "Group", new { area="Admin" })
```

Links would also be nicer IMHO:

```
/Admin/User
/Admin/Group
```